# Selenium WebDriver: How to teach webDriver that it is now looking at a new page

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a routine task at work. It opens a web page, authenticaes and then goes to a new page where I have to do more processing - selections, searches, button clicks etc.

I have the below piece of code with me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Using Chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

# Open the management console page.
driver.get("http://localhost:8183/mgmt/security/login.html")

print(driver.title)

# Select the username and the password text boxes
username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gwt-TextBox')
password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gwt-PasswordTextBox')

# Send username information
username.send_keys('sa-tcnxbot-gds')

# Send password information
password.send_keys('_r5l_\\1fpWu?L-]')

# Login to Teamcenter management console with the above set credentials.
signinbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('GFHWBTICII')
signinbutton.click()

# We are now in the main page.
tcservercomponent = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('GGDCJ-SFF GGDCJ-SHF GGDCJ-SPF')[0]
print( tcservercomponent.__sizeof__() )
```

Problem: What I am noticing is, after I am able to login by clicking the signin button initially, it takes me to a new page. But the 'driver' instance still appears to be listening to the old page. How would I tell it that I have moved on to a different page without page reload etc?. Please suggest.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: You could use ```dirver.title``` to find out on which page are you looking at. Also, If there is a redirect, you might want to wait until the title of the page appears, you can achieve that with ```assert "The title you want" in driver.title```

Comment: In my case the browser window/tag does not change it just updates with new content. i tried this one, but it did not work: WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "GGDCJ-SFF GGDCJ-SHF GGDCJ-SPF")))

Comment: If is loading new content, then probably some element on your website has a "loading" attribute the challenge here will be to find it, so you could use it as an element waiter.